# Amazon ECS Service Connect vs Amazon VPC Lattice

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-service-connect, amazon-vpc-lattice, ecs-service-connect

Looking at comparing and contrasting [ECS Service Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-connect.html) and [AWS VPC Lattice](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/lattice/). There are a lot of similarities and wondering what would make sense where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ECS Service Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-connect.html) is specific for [Amazon Elastic Container Service](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) providing a simplified approach for service discovery, traffic resilience and observability out of the box. The customers will need to have networking knowledge of VPC peering for any cross-VPC deployments as ECS Service Connect does not handle any of the underlying network connectivity. It is worthwhile to highlight that ECS Service Connect does not use VPC Lattice under the hood. 
Whereas [VPC Lattice](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/lattice/) is a way to automate connecting cross-account, cross-VPC microservices that are distributed across Kubernetes, native EC2/ASG and serverless environments eg Lambda, Fargate without needing any prior VPC networking experience. VPC Lattice provides fully automated VPC and inter-VPC networking without the need for sidecars, proxies. 
There is a roadmap item to integrate Amazon ECS with VPC Lattice with advanced features like authentication and authorization. At this time, you can configure ECS tasks in VPC Lattice as a service with a workaround and have an ALB/NLB as the target